# limit equaling zero at infinity

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

I have a problem where I found the percentage of cells as time approaches infinity to be $\frac{100d}{c+d}$. All parameters are positive constants. The question asks are there circumstances when this quantity can be zero? I think if $d$ is small and $c$ is large, the percentage is very close to zero. But if all parameters are positive is it true that the quantity can never actually be zero?

Comment: Even if only $d > 0$ the percentage must be nonzero since a fraction is equal to zero exactly when the numerator is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is true that if $c,d > 0$, then $\frac{100d}{c+d} > 0$ (so it can't equal $0$).

Comment: would you mind if I delete this problem?

Comment: I wouldn't mind. (Not sure if others would mind though.)

Comment: @user707991 Why are you deleting it?

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$\frac{100d}{c+d}=0 \iff d=0$$

and

$$\lim_{d/c\to 0} \frac{100d}{c+d}=0$$

$$\lim_{c/d\to \infty} \frac{100d}{c+d}=0$$

and you are right since all quantities are positive the ratio can't never be zero.

Comment: would you mind if I delete this problem?

Comment: No it is not  aproblem of course, since you are asking that! Bye